# PHP add two images together

Tags: php, imagemagick

How do I merge two images together with imagemagick, so that the bottom of image a is joined to the top of image b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets `$imtop` and `$imbottom` are our images

```
//imagesx($imtop)==imagesx($imbottom)
$new=imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($imtop),imagesy($imtop)+imagesy($imbottom));
imagecopy($new,$imtop,0,0,0,0,imagesx($imtop),imagesy($imtop));
imagecopy($new,$imbottom,0,imagesy($imtop),0,0,imagesx($imbottom),imagesy($imbottom));
//use $new
```